# One-click file opening in AppCode like in Xcode

Tags: appcode

Can we set AppCode to open a file with one click? The default is two click like on non-macOS systems.

It would be more natural for those used to opening files with one click in Xcode.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by, non-OS-X? Doest it mean, you can make an iOS app with AppCode in Windows OS too. ?

Answer (score 13):

In the gear menu for your project, select 'Autoscroll to source'. From the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/help/project-tool-window.html):

> If this option is on, AppCode automatically navigates from a file (or a class member) selected in the Project tool window to the corresponding source file (or its fragment) in the editor. If the corresponding file is not currently open, it will open automatically.

[image]